# Blacklist "Muscle" on Super User

Tags: support, spam, blacklist

The body building spam seems to be relentless and while lot more is blocked, we still see close to 4-5 posts every day about this.

A search for ["muscle"](https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=*muscle*%20deleted%3a1) indicates that so far there have been 445+ such posts. Can we add muscle to the blacklist?

Comment: hmm, potential for scunthrope effect? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUSCLE_%28alignment_software%29

Comment: hm, that should be a really low probability

Comment: Probably. I was wondering "What if there's software with that name". Damned spammers.

Comment: Just hit the gym guys

Comment: Lots of posts with the words "muscle memory" though..

Comment: @Raystafarian damn, that's a lot.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest fix would be to put all posts that contain "muscle" without "muscle memory" (since numerous questions use that phrase legitimately) through the Low Quality Posts review queue.

I realize that's not optimal, since LQP isn't really designed for flagging/identifying spam. An alternative would be to insert it as a task for First Posts *at the top* for quickest handling, since the vast majority of spam, in my experience, is its user's first and only post.

Maybe it would be nice if there was a Triage queue here like there is on Stack Overflow? If there is a secret internal examination place, problematic terms like "muscle" could be a good keyword to send stuff into there.

Comment: It's pretty rare for spam to last more than a minute or two before being deleted by flaggers.  SU has lots of users who flag spam they see on the main page.  A minority of users contribute on the review queues.  So it would add to queues that already could use more reviewers, and sit there longer than on the main page.

Comment: BTW, my belief is that this stuff really isn't spam in the sense that somebody is trying to sell something or attract people to malicious web pages.  They spend more time creating the post than it remains up, and nobody in their right mind would deal with the creators of these crude/ridiculous posts.  Seems more likely that it is people trolling the site with irritants.